# Plesk panel and new crm program

Tags: php, plesk

I am developing own customer relation manager program so   i need to manage e-mail accounts in plesk panel by my new crm program, but i don't know details. Can you help me about manage created e mail accounts by my new crm program

Comment: Did my answer happen to help you or do you still need guidance?

Comment: Thanks a lot but it couldnt help , Postfix  my plesk use , how can i us it with my own software

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may be of help to you is the plesk 'psa' database where the records on the panel are stored.

Not sure the ins and outs of it as I only have ever exported data from it but it can be accessed from:

Tools & Settings → Applications & Databases → Database Servers → MySQL → Then choose the psa database in the PhpMyAdmin sidebar

[image: PSA Database]